# Getting error -> unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript, error

root@kali:~/Documents/oraclize-test# npm run dev

> truffle-oraclize-api@0.0.2 dev /root/Documents/oraclize-test
>   webpack-dev-server

ERROR in ./app/javascripts/app.js
Module parse failed: /root/Documents/oraclize-test/app/javascripts/app.js Unexpected token (124:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|       })
|   }
|
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8081 ./app/javascripts/app.js
webpack: Failed to compile.

APP.JS

```
// Import the page's CSS. Webpack will know what to do with it, 
// as it's been configured by truffle-webpack
import "../stylesheets/app.css";

// Import libraries we need.
import { default as Web3} from 'web3';
import { default as contract } from 'truffle-contract'
// Import our contract artifacts and turn them into usable abstractions.
// Make sure you've ran truffle compile first
import contract_build_artifacts from '../../build/contracts/OraclizeTest.json'

// OraclizeContract is our usable abstraction, which we'll use through the code below.
var OraclizeContract = contract(contract_build_artifacts);

var accounts;
var account;

window.App = {

  // 'Constructor'
  start: function() {


    // Bootstrap the Contract abstraction for use with the current web3 instance
    OraclizeContract.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);

    // Get the initial account balance so it can be displayed.
    web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err, accs) {
      if (err != null) {
        alert("There was an error fetching your accounts.");
        return;
      }

      if (accs.length == 0) {
        alert("Couldn't get any accounts! Make sure your Ethereum client is configured correctly.");
        return;
      }

      accounts = accs;
      account = accounts[0];


    });
  },

  // Show an error
  setStatus: function(message) {
    var status = document.getElementById("status");
    status.innerHTML = message;
  },



}
// Front-end entry point

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    console.warn("Using web3 detected from external source. If you find that your accounts don't appear or you have 0 MetaCoin, ensure you've configured that source properly. If using MetaMask, see the following link. Feel free to delete this warning. :) http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask")
    // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
    window.web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
  } else {
    console.warn("No web3 detected. Falling back to http://127.0.0.1:9545. You should remove this fallback when you deploy live, as it's inherently insecure. Consider switching to Metamask for development. More info here: http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/truffle-and-metamask");
    // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node + in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
    window.web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:9545"));
  }

  // All systems go, start App!
  App.start();
});

document.getElementById("bet").addEventListener("submit", function(){


    var fromAddress1 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress1").value;
    var privateKey1 = document.querySelector("#bet #privateKey1").value;
    var fromAddress2 = document.querySelector("#bet #fromAddress2").value;
    var privateKey2 = document.querySelector("#bet #privateKey2").value;

    var betAmount = document.querySelector("#bet #betAmount").value;
    var contact = web3.eth.contract(OraclizeContract.abi);
    var sendata = contact.new.getData(web3.utils.toWei(betAmount, "ether"));

    var team = document.querySelector("#bet #team").value;

    if(team == "Home")
    {
      team = 1;
    }
    else
    {
      team = 2;
    }

    var contract = web3.eth.contract(OraclizeContract.abi).at(contractAddress);  
    var amount = contract.amount();
    var data = contract.betOnTeam.getData(team);


   var gasRequired = contract.betOnTeam.estimateGas(team, { 
          from: fromAddress,     
          value: amount,       
          to: contractAddress   
      })

   web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddress, function(error, nonce){

         var rawTx = {         
            gasPrice: web3.toHex(web3.eth.gasPrice), 
            gasLimit: web3.toHex(gasRequired),   
            from: fromAddress,         
            nonce: web3.toHex(nonce),          
            data: data,         
            to: contractAddress,         
            value: web3.toHex(amount)   };

       privateKey = EthJS.Util.toBuffer(privateKey, "hex");
       var tx = new EthJS.Tx(rawTx);         
        tx.sign(privateKey);

      })
  }
```

Webpack.config.js

```````````````````
const path = require('path');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/javascripts/app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: 'app.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    // Copy our app's index.html to the build folder.
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      { from: './app/index.html', to: "index.html" }
    ])
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
       test: /\.css$/,
       use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ]
      }
    ],
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader' },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react', "stage-2", "stage-3"],
          plugins: ['transform-runtime']
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
``````````````````
package.json
``````````````````
{
  "name": "truffle-oraclize-api",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "description": "Frontend example using truffle v3, Oraclize and an API",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./",
    "build": "webpack",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "author": "WWWillems",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.22.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.1.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.1.8",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-register": "^6.22.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "eslint": "^3.14.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-mocha": "^4.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": "^2.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "truffle-contract": "^1.1.11",
    "web3": "^0.20.0",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.3.0",
    "react": "16.8.4",
    "react-bootstrap": "1.0.0-beta.5",
    "react-dom": "16.8.4",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  }
}
```````````````````

Comment: This is a code-dump (you dumping your entire code here and asking others to figure it out for you). Please conduct a preliminary investigation, determine the minimal part in your code which is responsible for this problem, and if you still haven't figured it out by then, post ONLY that part here and explain what you've done and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you posted the full app.js, but your app.js is missing a circular bracket `)` right at the end.